# Relation between adjoint and dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, tensors, adjoint-operators, dual-spaces

I'm learning tensors recently. And I found that the notation for dual spaces $V^*$, the star, is the same as the notation  of adjoint operators. My definition of adjoint is the adjoint of $T \in L(V,W)$ such that $(x,T^*y)=(Tx,y)$. Since they have the same star *, I'm wondering if there are any hidden connections between them?

Comment: Your definition of the adjoint only applies if we have an inner product (or at least some non-degenerate bilinear form) over $V$. Are you aware of the more general definition of the adjoint of an operator between vector spaces for which $T^* \in L(W^*,V^*)$?

Comment: @Ben Grossmann Sorry, what do you mean by non-degenerate bilinear form? I think my definition is in finite-dimensions. I'm not sure about the more general definition.

Comment: If you haven't encountered that phrase, don't worry about it. The question is: does your definition of adjoint require $(x,y)$ to be defined for $x,y \in V$?

Comment: No. In this case, $x\in V, y\in W$, because $T\in L(V,W)$.

Comment: But $Tx \in W$ and $y \in W$, which means that $(Tx,y)$ is an expression of the form $(w_1,w_2)$ with $w_1,w_2 \in W$. Similarly, $T^*$ is presumably defined to be a map from $W$ to $V$, so that $x$ and $T^*y$ are elements of $V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a connection. In general, given $T\in L(V, W)$ we can define $T^*\in L(W^*, V^*)$ by the rule $T^*(f)=f\circ T$.

In the special case when $X$ is a finite dimensional inner product space, all the elements of $X^*$ are of the form $f_y(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$ for some $y\in X$. So in this case we can think of linear functionals simply as elements of $X$.

Now assume $V, W$ are some finite dimensional inner product spaces. Given $T\in L(V,W)$ we can as usual define $T^*: W^*\to V^*$. But if we remember the correspondence between $V$ and $V^*$, and between $W$ and $W^*$, we can instead define a map $T^*: W\to V$.

So, let $y\in W$. Then $T^*y$ is an element of $V$, and hence it defines the linear functional $T^*y(x)=\langle x,T^*y\rangle_V$ in $V^*$. On the other hand, $T^*$ has to satisfy $T^*y=y\circ T$, and so this functional in $V^*$ is defined by:

$T^*y(x)=y(T(x))=\langle T(x), y\rangle_W$

So this intuitively explains why $\langle T(x),y\rangle_W=\langle x,T^*y\rangle_V$ has to hold. This is the motivation for your definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still confused about the rule you mentioned: ∗()=∘ . How should I comprehend this  $f$?

Comment: $f$ is an element of $W^*$, i.e a linear functional $f:W\to F$ where $F$ is the field we are working in. Then the composition $f\circ T$ is a map $V\to F$, and it is easy to check it is linear, which means it is an element of $V^*$. So indeed $T^*$ maps elements of $W^*$ to elements of $V^*$.

Comment: I also have a question on how you derive $T^*:W \rightarrow V$ from $T^*:W^* \rightarrow V^*$. Could you explain more on that? I don't know what the correspondence you are referring to.

Comment: @Kylinny In the second paragraph: "all the elements of $X^*$ are of the form $f_y(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$ for some $y\in X$". That is the correspondence

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think functionals $W^*$ and $V^*$ are taking vectors into scalars. Why can we ignore that scalar in  $^∗$:→?

Comment: @Kylinny As I explained, each element in $W^*$ (and same thing in $V^*$) has the form $f_y(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$ for some $y\in W$. So the correspondence between $W$ and $W^*$ is simply $y\to f_y$. This is a bijection.

Comment: Oh can I treat this as isomorphism?

Comment: @Kylinny There is no scalar being ignored. For any $w \in W$, $f(w)$ is a scalar. For any $v \in V$, $T^*f(v) = (f \circ T)(v) =  f(T(v))$ is a scalar. The objects of interest is not the scalar outputs; we are concerned with the functions that produce these outputs.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you so much!